# Production entry for rails database.yml file on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Just looking at my database.yml file for my Rails 4 app and noticed there isn't any setting for the production database - only the test and development ones.

I don't actually have any issues but wanted to avoid other potential issues by posting this question.

Locally I use a PG database and I host my app on Heroku using a PG db too.

Should I have some settings in the yml for the production database file as I'm really not sure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whatever you place in database.yml will be overwritten by Heroku during production deployment, as it uses its own application configuration to effectively write a new one.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#build-behavior

Unless you need to deploy the database.yml to other environments, you can include it in gitignore

Comment: actually trying to run this command `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` because I have an image that won't update but getting an error - thought it might be something to do with not having a setting for production.

Comment: Well it wouldn't hurt to have a production entry in there, just with some fake user and password, in case anything in your system wanted to know that the production system was also postgres, but a link with a precompile issue sounds unlikely to me. The Gemfile ought to be more influential, I'd think.

Comment: In case anyone else is wanting to connect to the heroku production database from a local console, this is the easiest way I found to get the proper configuration settings.

  `heroku run rails runner 'puts ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.to_yam'`

Answer (score 10):

The above answers are no longer valid for Rails 4.x on Heroku. Heroku no longer overwrites your database.yml. You need the following entry in your config/database.yml file:

```
production:
   url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Comment: For Rails 4.1+ on heroku, to be a bit more precise.

Answer (score 4):

If you host your application on Heroku and use a Heroku Postgres DB you don't need a production entry in your database.yml.

Heroku will replace your database.yml entirely with one that uses the DATABASE_URL from heroku:config.

So no, you don't need a production entry in your database.yml for Heroku-hosted apps.